# Pandas dataframe first instance of value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df:

```
                     Voltage
01-02-2017 00:00       13.1
01-02-2017 00:01       13.2
01-02-2017 00:02       13.3
01-02-2017 00:03       14.1
01-02-2017 00:04       14.3
01-02-2017 00:04       13.5
```

I would like the time (hh:mm) of the first instance of when the value in the Voltage column >=14.0. There should only be one time value in column 'Time of Full Charge'.

```
                     Voltage   Time of Full Charge
01-02-2017 00:00       13.1
01-02-2017 00:01       13.2
01-02-2017 00:02       13.3
01-02-2017 00:03       14.1         00:03
01-02-2017 00:04       14.3
01-02-2017 00:04       13.5
```

I am trying something along these lines, but cannot figure it out:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.['Time of Full Charge'] = np.where(df.['Voltage'] >= 14.0), (df.index.hour:df.index.minute))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for first index value by condition, only is necessary index has to be unique:

```
idx = (df['Voltage'] >= 14.0).idxmax()
df.loc[mask, 'Time of Full Charge'] = mask.idxmax().strftime('%H:%M')
print (df)
                     Voltage Time of Full Charge
2017-01-02 00:00:00     13.1                 NaN
2017-01-02 00:01:00     13.2                 NaN
2017-01-02 00:02:00     13.3                 NaN
2017-01-02 00:03:00     14.1               00:03
2017-01-02 00:04:00     14.3                 NaN
2017-01-02 00:04:00     13.5                 NaN
```

Or:

```
idx = (df['Voltage'] >= 14.0).idxmax()
df['Time of Full Charge'] = np.where(df.index == idx, idx.strftime('%H:%M'), '')
print (df)
                     Voltage Time of Full Charge
2017-01-02 00:00:00     13.1                    
2017-01-02 00:01:00     13.2                    
2017-01-02 00:02:00     13.3                    
2017-01-02 00:03:00     14.1               00:03
2017-01-02 00:04:00     14.3                    
2017-01-02 00:04:00     13.5
```

For non unique index is possible use `MultiIndex`:

```
df.index = [np.arange(len(df.index)), df.index]

idx = (df['Voltage'] >= 14.0).idxmax()
df['Time of Full Charge'] = np.where(df.index.get_level_values(0) == idx[0], 
                                     idx[1].strftime('%H:%M'),
                                     '')

df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
print (df)
                     Voltage Time of Full Charge
2017-01-02 00:00:00     13.1                    
2017-01-02 00:01:00     13.2                    
2017-01-02 00:02:00     13.3                    
2017-01-02 00:03:00     14.1               00:03
2017-01-02 00:04:00     14.3                    
2017-01-02 00:04:00     13.5
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I only need the first instance of when that column reaches 14 or above (there should only be one value in the new column. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, index is essentially a 24 hour day, so will be unique. thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be idxmin() instead of idxmax()? Because when you say that df['Voltage'] >= 14, it means only those rows with values greater than or equal to 14 will be present. Now, amongst those rows, we just need the minimum one. Kindly let me know where am I wrong.

Comment: @ArchanJoshi - It is a bit different, because working with boolen mask - `True`s with `False`s. So for match first `True` need `idxmax`, because `True`s is processes like `1`, `False` like `0`. So first index of `'1' (`True`)` is extracted by `idxmax`. And there is no filtering, `(df['Voltage'] >= 14.0)` does not filter.

Comment: Ah I see. Ok. Just a little suggestion bro. You are an awesome and highly knowledgeable person. Just improve your English a little bit, as there could  sometimes be some problems with understanding. But, anyway, thanks man. Thanks a lot for the promptness and the explanation.

Comment: @ArchanJoshi - Thank you, I know it - my English is not so nice :(

Comment: @ArchanJoshi - Ya, still thinking about your comment... Hmmm, really good suggestion. I used calan methofdfor English in past, but stop it. So I try to learn again.

Comment: Source doesn't matter. Just pick any good one and start. You'll be done in no time. It is not at all a difficult language.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy.searchsorted()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) if `Voltage` column is sorted:

```
In [260]: df.index[np.searchsorted(df.Voltage, 14)]
Out[260]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-02 00:03:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```